# Myram Lamm - how to apply magic abilities?

Tags: time-stories, a-prophecy-of-dragons

In A Prophecy of Dragons, how does one correctly apply the magic abilities of Myriam Lamm? As an example, Myst Bolt shows `1 star: remove 2 shields` from your space. What happens if you roll more than 1 star?

Does it mean that you can remove 2 shields for **every star you roll**, or merely that if you roll **one or more** stars you can take 2 shields off, no matter how many you roll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member of Space Cowboys cleared this up in a [Board Game Geek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1514064/few-more-rules-questions-spoilers):

> Maryam should actually be worded more precisely. This is a typo and
> will be corrected in the next printing.
>
> Mystic Bolt: 1 star or more:
>
> Minor Healing: 1 star or more:
>
> Divine Healing: 2 stars or more:

Answer (score 0):

If you compare to other spells, it seems to me that it must mean if you roll 1 or more stars, you get to remove two shields. Additional stars have no extra effect. So more magic skill would just increase the chances that you would get to remove 2 shields, rather than no shields.